# ERROR ITMS-90684

Tags: ios, app-store, info.plist

I have this Error 
 in  upload app from Xcode

ERROR ITMS-90684: "The Info.plist file at myapp.app/info.atlasc/info.plist is currently named info.plist. Info.plist filename is case-sensitive and must be exactly named as 'Info.plist'"
ERROR ITMS-90684: "The Info.plist file at myapp.app/info.atlasc/info.plist is currently named info.plist. Info.plist filename is case-sensitive and must be exactly named as 'Info.plist'"

Comment: Yes I read it but I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: rename "info.plist" to "Info.plist" as the error says

Comment: already the name is Info.pilst

Comment: It isn't otherwise you wouldn't get the error.  I suggest you check the file in finder or there terminal